# not able to use 'this' keyword in react?

Tags: reactjs

this is the code i'm using

```
state = {
        x_axis:"",
        y_axis:"",
        mapdata:[],
        priority:[]
    }

<div className="inverted">{this.state.y_axis}</div>
                            <div >
                                <table>
                                
                                    <tbody >  
                                 
                                    {this.state.mapdata.map( function( row ) {
                                        return (
                                        <tr>
                                        {row.map( function( item ) { 
                                            return (
                                                <th  style={{
                                                   
                                                    backgroundColor:  `${this.state[item.id]}`,
                                                }}>
                                                    <>
                                                        <tr scope="row"  >
                                                            <OverlapDropdown defaultvalue={item.priority} options={options}handleChange={(e)=>this.giveColor(e.value,item.id)}/>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </>
                                                </th>
                                            )
                                        } )}
                                        </tr>

                                    )
                                    } )}
                                    
                                       
                                    </tbody>
                                    
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

it's showing the error, cannot read property of undefined.
i/m not able to use super(props), it's showing restricted.
is there some other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use arrow function or `this` will refer to `function` instead of `class` instance where `this.state` refers to.

```
row.map((item) => {
  return (
    <th
      style={{
        backgroundColor: `${this.state[item.id]}`,
      }}
    >
      <>
        <tr scope="row">
          <OverlapDropdown
            defaultvalue={item.priority}
            options={options}
            handleChange={(e) => this.giveColor(e.value, item.id)}
          />
        </tr>
      </>
    </th>
  );
});
```